# Client side or server side error on SecurityTokenValidationException certificate expiration

Tags: c#, exception, certificate, x509

I am having some trouble with an issue using client-server authentication with an specific client in WCF. This client has updated the certificates in his website but when he tries to  establish a channel to my application The program gets a negotiation error. My question is with the information that I can get from the server, is it possible to check if the problem is located on  client side or server side ?

We have been looking the server side for the new certificates  and checked that the new ones are installed as trusted people correctly.
We checked also the new website  and found the new certificate installed
what we could not check is if the application client is using this certificate.
it is not possible to contact the client.

The binding is configured to must accept certificates on client connection:

```
<binding name="XXX">
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" establishSecurityContext="false" negotiateServiceCredential="false"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
```

We are getting this error on negotiation:

> SecurityTokenValidationException: The X.509 certificate (CN=,
>   OU=Domain Control Validated) usage time is invalid.  The usage time
>   '7/30/2019 9:14:23 AM' does not fall between NotBefore time 'time ago'
>   and NotAfter time '[days ago]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the client did renew the certificate in his website but it didn't in the call to the webservice. In fact it was in client side.